# detect 64-bit CPU in Ruby on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, 64-bit

I'm looking to differentiate between Core Solo/Duo and Core 2 Duo processors for 64-bit support.

On a Core 2 Duo, then `` `sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable` `` gives `1`, as desired, but on a 32-bit processor, it throws an error, saying:

```
second level name cpu64bit_capable in hw.cpu64bit_capable is invalid
```

What's the best way to detect a 64-bit processor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use your `sysctl` command by looking at the command's return value.

```
$ irb
>> system("sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable > /dev/null 2>&1")
=> true
```

On 32 bit CPU it should return `false`.

---

Alternatively, depending what you're really looking for, you can test for 64 bit EFI with `ioreg`, though I think your CPU could still be 64 bit with a 32 bit EFI.

On a 64 bit EFI machine, you'd get this:

```
$ irb
>> system("ioreg -l -p IODeviceTree | grep firmware-abi | grep -q EFI64")
=> true
```

On a machine lacking 64 bit EFI, you'd get `false`.